# OpenERP login issue

Tags: python, linux, odoo

Locally made an openerp set up in ubuntu, when i am trying to login,then gets an error like this

```
 Your version of OpenERP is unsupported. Support & maintenance services are available here: OpenERP Entreprise.

OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 180, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(controller, self, **self.params)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 498, in authenticate
    req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/common/session.py", line 73, in authenticate
    uid = self.proxy('common').authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 117, in proxy
    result = self.connector.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 608, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 593, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 397, in dispatch
return fn(*params)
```

Comment: please add some more information. which version of openerp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i am checked the openerp-server.log i got an error

```
2013-03-19 11:28:09,249 1486 ERROR zeon1 openerp.sql_db: Programming error:  column ir_module_module.maintainer does not exist
LINE 1: ...dule."menus_by_module",ir_module_module."website",ir_module_...
```

Here i  created the db using openerp client whose version is less than 6 but my openerp server was 6.1,so i got that error.Here i created new db using openerp server 6.1,now it is working as expected.